# How to get another file content from content script in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch

I have a chrome extension with files like this:

```
.
├── settings.json
├── manifest.json
└── ContentScript.js
```

with manifest like this

```
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "ContentScript.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "matches": ["https://example.com"]
        }
    ]
```

How to get data from `settings.json` in ContentScript.js?

Comment: web_accessible_resources + chrome.runtime.getURL + fetch.

Comment: Can you explain it ?

Comment: I thought you would find an example yourself :-) but if you got it working then add an answer with the real code so it can be used by others.

Comment: I found good decision. And then did it but I misstyped name of file. It working now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly add this to manifest:

```json
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "settings.json"
    ]
```

To force file to be accessable.

You can access it on url

```js
chrome.runtime.getURL("settings.json")
```

Full solution:

```js
(async () => {
    var text = await fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL("settings.json")).then((responce) => {
        if (responce.ok) {
            return responce.text()// or responce.json() to json-style object
        } else { throw "Error: File was not found or can't be reached" }
    })
}).call()
```